# Show and Hide Spans Infinitely

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
<span class="site-title">
<span>M</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>i</span>
<span>k</span>
<span>a</span>
</span>
```

Letters are hidden. I would like to show letters one by one infinitely.

Letter 'M' shows (display: block), wait 500ms and hides (display: none), then Letter 'o' shows, wait 500ms and hides, and so on in a circle.

Can someone help please? I need done this in pure JavaScript, not jQuery for a certain reason.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to use an ES6 generator function:

```js
function* displayLetters(){
  while(true){
    const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.site-title span')
    for(const letter of letters){
      letter.classList.add('active')
      yield
      letter.classList.remove('active')
    }
  }
}

const iterator = displayLetters()
iterator.next()
setInterval(() => iterator.next(), 500)
```

```css
.site-title span{
  display: none;
}
.site-title span.active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="site-title">
  <span>M</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>n</span>
  <span>i</span>
  <span>k</span>
  <span>a</span>
</span>
```

Comment: thanks!) Really appreciate that. Can I ask you one more thing please? It's possible to stop this? I use a js plugin with done event, so can I add a stop function to it?

Comment: Hint: use `clearInterval` to clear the timeout. You can restart it using the `setInterval(...)` line later